# Lossless rotation of video (MPG, MP4)?

Tags: video, video-conversion, video-encoding

It is possible -- indeed, quite easy -- to rotate JPEG-files without re-encoding them, which means, no *additional* loss of quality is introduced in the process.

Is the same possible for the similarly-lossy *video*-formats (MPG, MP4)?

Comment: By 90 degrees, and without changing the resolution? E.g. 848x480 would become 480x848? I think that should be possible if the macro blocks etc. are symmetric wrt. vertical/horizontal dimensions, which IIRC they are. But I don't know any tool which would do it. 180 degrees should definitely be possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For some containers (e.g. MOV and MP4) you can set a rotation flag without changing the actual video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=<x> output.mp4
```

Here, replace `<x>` with 0 to disable any existing rotation, or any value like 90, 180 or 270 to rotate the displayed video. Note that some players may ignore these flags.

See also: [Can I set rotation field for a video stream with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15336581/435093)

Comment: Also works with .3gp.