# How do you rotate an entire directory of videos with ffmpeg?

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, batch, rotate

I'm new to FFmpeg and trying to figure this out. I found this for [Batch processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784661/how-do-you-convert-an-entire-directory-with-ffmpeg) and this answer for [rotation of video](https://superuser.com/questions/1164650/lossless-rotation-of-video-mpg-mp4) but I need to put them together.

Could someone please explain how to create a script for this action, on Windows?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Use `for` command with ffmpeg command. But the syntax of `for` command may vary according to OS.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses. To clarify, I'm trying to accomplish this on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you just need to look the files up, (store them in a variable,) and then feed those looked up files into FFmpeg.

Of course, [Windows's Batch-language would be sufficient for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16142093/8013879). But since I have zero proficiency with that, here's a PowerShell-Script:

```cs
# Searching for files with the Get-ChildItem cmdlet and saving their relevant properties in an array:
# NOTE: -File will only work with PowerShell-versions >= 3.
[array]$FilesToRotate = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\PATH_TO_FILES" ((-Filter *.mp4)) ((-Recurse)) -File | ForEach-Object {
    # NOTE: This part is a bit tricky - I just added it so I'm able to save the parent-path of each file in an object.
    # NOTE: One could also omit the whole ForEach-Object and use the Split-Path cmdlet inside the output-file's specification in FFmpeg's code.
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        InFullName = $_.FullName
        # Will put the output-file in the same folder as the input-file and add "_ROTATION" as suffix in its name.
        OutFullName = "$(Split-Path -Parent -Path $($_.FullName))\$($_.BaseName)_ROTATE$($_.Extension)"
    }
}

# Processing the files with FFmpeg using PowerShell's Start-Process cmdlet:
for($i=0; $i -lt $FilesToRotate.Length; $i++){
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\PATH_TO_FFMPEG\ffmpeg.exe" -Argumentlist " -i `"$($FilesToRotate[$i].InFullName)`" -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=<x> `"$($FilesToRotate[$i].OutFullName )`" " ((-Wait)) ((-NoNewWindow))
}
```

This script will run FFmpeg with the [code you provided](https://superuser.com/questions/1164650/lossless-rotation-of-video-mpg-mp4) (I did not check it, but you can easily replace it anyway) and save the resulting file into the same folder with the name-suffix "_ROTATE" - so "MyMovie2017.mov" will become "MyMovie2017_ROTATE.mov". (If you want to render them to a whole new folder, replace `$($FilesToRotate[$i].ParentPath)` with the path you like.)

Notes: things in doubled parentheses `(( ))` are optional:

- `-Filter` will only adress (one) specific type of files, e.g. *.mp4 will only find MP4-Files. If you have more than one file-type, but many files you do not need to convert (like text-files), you could either `-Exclude` all formats you don't want to convert or `-Include` only those which should be converted (`-Include` is like `-Filter` - it is slower, but can include more than one format.)
- `-Recurse` will also look into subfolders. You could also use `-Depth`with PowerShell v 5+.
- `-Wait` will open one ffmpeg-instance at a time - without it, all instances will be opened parallel.
- `-NoNewWindow` will show the output of your ffmpeg-instance at the PowerShell-Console, while without it, every instance of ffmpeg will open in a new console-window. Makes sense only with `-Wait`.

You will have to delete all doubled parentheses (and the content of them if you don't want it) before starting the script.

Also, these things need to be adapted:

- `C:\PATH_TO_FILES` Path to your files, obviously.
- `C:\PATH_TO_FFMPEG\ffmpeg.exe` Path to your ffmpeg.exe, obviously.
- `rotate=<x>` - you need to replace the `<x>` with either `90`, `180`, or `270`. (As explained at the code's source)

If anything needs more explanation, I'm happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got it to work after some trial and error by removing your "-File" text.
So it looked like this ontop: 

[array]$FilesToRotate = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\PATH_TO_FILES"

Comment: Could you tell me what the "-File" was supposed to do? I just deleted it after it errored and got it working.

Comment: `-File` will prevent `Get-ChildItem` from including folders into the variable. Without `-File` (and/or `-Filter`), `$FilesToRotate` would include even subfolders, so PowerShell would try to pass your subfolder(s) as an input-file for FFmpeg. Note that we're talking about the folder itself; we're not talking about recursive search here.
[The documentation of Get.-ChildItem can be found here.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: @ThirteenthMonth could you tell me what error it throws? When I try it with `-File`, it works flawlessly. Also, could you tell me the version of PS you're using? (Simply type `$PSVersionTable` into the console and hit enter - it's the first value.) Thank you very much!

Comment: Inputting $PSVersionTable I got all of this:

""PS C:\Users\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.8669
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1""

Yeah I removed -Recurse, -Filter for testing without, and then as soon as -File was removed it worked. It's my first time with this so idk the cause.

Comment: Ah - in PowerShell < version 3, the `-File`-parameter wasn't included. If you would really like to use it, I'd suggest you upgrade your PowerShell-installation, though that would be a bit overkill just to convert a few files. ;-)
Anyway, I added that information into the script as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

## One Line Solution

```
npx rotate-video --source=source_path --destination=destination_path --extension=MP4 --angel=270
```

**Note:** You need to install `FFMPEG` CLI first [install](https://github.com/numandev1/rotate-video#prerequisite)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).